# Template not found error for Cucumber-HTML-Report

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber

I'm trying to generate cucumber-html-report after execution, but getting error-
"Template file ../node_modules/cucumber-html-report/ does not exist! Aborting"
Can anyone help here. npmjs.com says report should pick default template but it's not working for me.
I can post my hook.ts here if required

```
const Cucumber = require('cucumber');
let report = require('cucumber-html-report');
import { browser } from 'protractor';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { config } from '../config/config';
import { defineSupportCode } from "cucumber";
import * as reporter from 'cucumber-html-reporter';
import { mkdirp } from 'mkdirp';

defineSupportCode(function ({ registerHandler, registerListener, After,         setDefaultTimeout }) {
setDefaultTimeout(10 * 1000);
let jsonReports = process.cwd() + "/reports/json";
let htmlReports = process.cwd() + "/reports/html";
let targetJson = jsonReports + "/cucumber_report.json";

registerHandler('BeforeFeature', async function () {
    await browser.get(config.baseUrl);
});

After(async function (scenarioResult) {
    let world = this;
    if (scenarioResult.isFailed()) {
        let screenShot = await browser.takeScreenshot();
        world.attach(screenShot, 'image/png');
    }
})

let cucumberReporterOptions = {
    theme: "bootstrap",
    jsonFile: targetJson,
    output: htmlReports + "/cucumber_reporter.html",
    reportSuiteAsScenarios: true
};

let logFn = string => {
    if (!fs.existsSync(jsonReports)) {
        mkdirp.sync(jsonReports);
    }
    try {
        fs.writeFileSync(targetJson, string);
        reporter.generate(cucumberReporterOptions); 
        report.create({
            source:       targetJson,      
            dest:         htmlReports,                   
            name:         'MyReport.html',                 
            title:        'Cucumber Report',            
        })
    } catch (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(`Failed to save cucumber test results to json file. 
                         Failed to create html report.
                         `);
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
};
let jsonformatter = new Cucumber.JsonFormatter({
    log: logFn
});
registerListener(jsonformatter);
```

})

Comment: please provide more info, like your hook, your config, so we can help you

Comment: It was my mistake while calling the create function. Now it's working perfectly fine, posted my working hooks file here. 
Thanks @wswebcreation for your time